# How to conditionally select an array in dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, slice

I have a dictionary with the following form:

- The keys are 0-9.
- The value is an array, which contains 4 parameters (dtype=float).
- For every value in the array there is a criterion (e.g. is the value >1?). If one value does not fulfill its criterion, the whole entry is removed from the dictionary.

  - In other words: only the entries, in which all 4 value from the array fulfill their individual criterion, are move to a new dictionary)

```py
{0: array([-1.37979662, 1.2237947 , 1.02293956, 2.84491658]),
 1: array([-1.32019091, 1.17396212, 1.01325119, 2.89558077]),
 2: array([-1.29436374, 0.93597102, 1.06104517, 2.92670774]),
 3: array([-1.24879849, 1.04383302, 1.06866074, 2.41867709]),
 4: array([-1.1299237 , 0.72485214, 1.04738796, 2.16609311]),
 5: array([-1.08398485, 0.96394932, 1.03896677, 2.34082866]),
 6: array([-1.24153984, 0.82464176, 1.08445227, 2.6564374 ]),
 7: array([-1.04296362, 0.52683467, 1.10769773, 2.32662654]),
 8: array([-1.34813309, 0.76031429, 1.01582122, 2.60977459]),
 9: array([-1.20303226, 0.79573596, 1.03138351, 2.41515303])}
```

Any hint is appreciated, thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ***For every value in the array there is a criterion (e.g. is the value >1?)***

  - None of the keys in the sample met the criterion, so I updated `data[9]` to do so.
- The following [`dict comprehension`](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/#using-comprehensions) satisfies the criterion to include only the `key: value` pairs, where all values in the `np.array` are `>1`.
- [`.all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) is a built-in python function

  - `np.array([ True,  True,  True,  True]).all()` -> `True`
  - `np.array([ False,  True,  True,  True]).all()` -> `False`

```py
import numpy as np

data = {0: np.array([-1.37979662, 1.2237947 , 1.02293956, 2.84491658]),
        1: np.array([-1.32019091, 1.17396212, 1.01325119, 2.89558077]),
        2: np.array([-1.29436374, 0.93597102, 1.06104517, 2.92670774]),
        3: np.array([-1.24879849, 1.04383302, 1.06866074, 2.41867709]),
        4: np.array([-1.1299237 , 0.72485214, 1.04738796, 2.16609311]), 
        5: np.array([-1.08398485, 0.96394932, 1.03896677, 2.34082866]), 
        6: np.array([-1.24153984, 0.82464176, 1.08445227, 2.6564374 ]),
        7: np.array([-1.04296362, 0.52683467, 1.10769773, 2.32662654]),
        8: np.array([1.34813309, 0.76031429, 1.01582122, -2.60977459]),
        9: np.array([1.20303226, 1.79573596, 1.03138351, 2.41515303])}

# dict comprehension
data1 = {k: v for k, v in data.items() if (v > 1.0).all()}

print(data1)
>>> {9: array([1.20303226, 1.79573596, 1.03138351, 2.41515303])}
```

### For multiple conditions

```py
data2 = {k: v for k, v in data.items() if v[0] > 1 if v[1] > 0 if v[2] > 1 if v[3] < -2}

print(data2)

>>> {8: array([ 1.34813309,  0.76031429,  1.01582122, -2.60977459])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each value is a `numpy` array you can check the condition on the whole array at once since basic operations are vectorized.

```
{k: v for k, v in data.items() if sum(v > -1.1) == len(v)}

{5: array([-1.08398485,  0.96394932,  1.03896677,  2.34082866]),
 7: array([-1.04296362,  0.52683467,  1.10769773,  2.32662654])}
```

When you do `array > value` it returns an array of booleans, which we can sum. If the sum of this boolean array is the length of the array then we know every item met the condition set forth. I used `-1.1` to show it works as intended given none of the values in this dictionary meet the `> 1` criteria.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `np.where` since you have a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np


my_dict = {0: np.array([-1.37979662, 1.2237947 , 1.02293956, 2.84491658]),
        1: np.array([-1.32019091, 1.17396212, 1.01325119, 2.89558077]),
        2: np.array([-1.29436374, 0.93597102, 1.06104517, 2.92670774]),
        3: np.array([-1.24879849, 1.04383302, 1.06866074, 2.41867709]),
        4: np.array([-1.1299237 , 0.72485214, 1.04738796, 2.16609311]),
        5: np.array([-1.08398485, 0.96394932, 1.03896677, 2.34082866]),
        6: np.array([-1.24153984, 0.82464176, 1.08445227, 2.6564374 ]),
        7: np.array([-1.04296362, 0.52683467, 1.10769773, 2.32662654]),
        8: np.array([-1.34813309, 0.76031429, 1.01582122, 2.60977459]),
        9: np.array([1.20303226, 1.79573596, 1.03138351, 2.41515303])}

new_dict = {}
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    temp = value if len(value[np.where(value > 1)]) == len(value) else -1
    if not isinstance(temp, int):
        new_dict[key] = temp

# output = {9: array([1.20303226, 1.79573596, 1.03138351, 2.41515303])}
```